# How to use the hashtags on twitter using python?

Tags: python, hashtag

Can anyone tell me how to use retrieve hashtags from Twitter in Python? I have tried using:

```
test = api.GetUserTimeline()
for i in test:
    text = i.text
    hashtag = i.hashtags
    print text
    print "\n" + hashtag
```

It returns `hashtag` as `None`, while in the text it is "life is #wonderful"

Comment: It would help if you specified which of the Twitter API libraries you were using.

Comment: i am using python-twitter-0.8.1 as my Twitter API libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the underlying Twitter API doesn't actually parse out hashtags for you, and neither does the python-twitter wrapper. (*Of course, I didn't look very hard ;)*)

Fortunately, it's pretty easy to do this yourself. Hashtags are words that start with '#'; so we ask Python for each word that starts with '#', with that '#' removed (i.e., from the second character to the end of the word), where the words come from splitting the text into words. It's almost clearer in Python than in English:

```
 hashtags = [word[1:] for word in i.text.split() if word.startswith('#')]
```

Comment: thanks for the advice. I am able to do it manually by using if statement and check for the '#'. I thought there is a shortcut by using twiiter API command. anyway thanks for the guidance. greatly appreciated.